# Torsion-freeness of the group $\langle a, b \mid a b^m = ba^n\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

For integers $m$ and $n$ let $K(m,n)$ be the group $\langle a, b \mid a b^m = ba^n\rangle$. Is there a special name for this group? Is there a complete characterization of those pairs $(m,n)$ for which the group is torsion-free? Or bi-orderable (in the sense of Rolfsen: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~rolfsen/papers/luminynotes/lum.pdf)?

Comment: They see m to be word hyperbolic when $|a|, |b|>1$ except for a few small values of $a,b$.

Comment: Just in case this may help: I can prove that the $K(1,n)$ is not bi-orderable. But the general case defeats me.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why are they hyperbolic?

Comment: It was a computer calculation, which verifies that geodesic bigons in the Cayley graph are uniformly thin. One or two of the smaller ones, such as $K(2,2)$, are automatic but (apparently) not hyperbolic.

Answer (score 4):

These groups are torsion-free groups with a single defining relation, which implies that they are right-orderable. I do not know if they are bi-orderable though.

A *one-relator group* is a group with a presentation of the form $\langle X; S\rangle$ where $X$ is some set (possibly infinite) and $S$ is an arbitrary word. Your groups are clearly one-relator groups, and they are torsion-free because every one-relator group has torsion if and only if the relator $S$ is a proper power of some other element $R$ in $F(X)$, that is, $S\equiv R^n$ for $n>1$. This follows from the fact that you can always use HNN-extensions and free products with amalgamation to write such a group in terms of another one-relator group where the relator has strictly shorter length. This gives you an induction step. This induction idea is called Magnus' method, after Wilhelm Magnus, and Lyndon and Schupp's book goes into this interpretation of Magnus' method a wee bit, but they prefer Magnus' original (rather messy) approach. If you want a neat proof, look up the paper *The Freiheitsstatz and its extensions* of Fine and Rosenberger. This is in a book though, so you could look up the paper of McCool and Schupp entitled *One-relator groups and HNN-extensions*.

These groups are *locally-indicable* because they are torsion-free one-relator groups (see the paper *On locally indicable groups*, 1982, by Jim Howie), that is, every finitely-generated subgroup maps into the infinite cyclic group. This means that they are right-orderable (see the paper *A note on group rings of certain torsion free groups*, 1972, by Burns and Hale). I do not know if they are bi-orderable though.

EDIT: I have just looked over the notes you link too, and you should realise that my last paragraph is expanded on in the notes.

Comment: But the given presentations are not the same as $BS(m,n)$.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I knew about Baumslag-Solitar, but not about Magnus' method and the result on HNN-extensions. Yet, Baumslag-Solitar groups are defined by a different presentation than the one defining $K(m,n)$, aren't they?

Comment: Hmm. Apparently I cannot read. I'll remove the bit about Baumslag-Solitar groups...

Answer (score 3):

Proposition 5.18 from Lyndon, Schupp, *Combinatorial Group Theory*,  Springer, 1977:

If $G = \langle X; r=1\rangle$ and $r$ is not a proper power, then $G$ is torsion free.